# Cómo puedo modificar datos de una clase padre creandola como una clase hija?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tengo 4 clases del modelo que son:

```
    public class Padre
    {
public Padre()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public decimal Importe { get; set}
    }
public class Historial
        {
    public Historial()
            {

            }
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Usuario{ get; set; }

            public Datetime Fecha{ get; set}
public int padreId{ get; set}
[ForeignKey("padreId")]
            public virtual Padre Padre{ get; set; }
        }

    public class Hija : Padre
    {
        public Hija(){}

        public int otroId { get; set}

        [ForeignKey("otroId ")]
        public virtual Otro Otro { get; set; }
    }

    public class Otro
    {
        public Otro()
{
Hija= new HashSet<Hija>();
}
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public datetime fecha { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set}

        [InverseProperty("Otro")]
        public virtual ICollection<Hija> Hija{ get; set; }
    }
```

Existe en la base de datos  **datos** de la clase `Padre` pero cuando trato insertar datos de la clase `Hija` me da error de llave duplicada, por ejemplo he realizado esto:

```
var padre=context.Padre.find(1);
context.Entry(padre).State=EntityState.Detached;
var hijo= new Hijo()
{
Id=padre.Id;
otroId=2;
}
context.Entry(hijo).State=EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Los datos de la clase Padre no se pueden **eliminar** porque existe otra clase que tienen datos que hacen referencia a sus datos. Necesito saber si alguien a podido lograr insertar datos de una clase `Hija` cuando ya existe datos de una clase `Padre` o mejor dicho Convertir los datos de una padre en datos de una hija sin modificar ni cambiar el Id o llave primaria.

El Entity Framework es la versión 6..

Comment: pero la clase Otro no deberia heredar de Padre ? La verdad no entiendo que relacion hay entre crear la clase Otro y despues la clase Hija si en principio estas no tienen ningun tipo de relacion

Comment: Esa son clases de modelo hechas en Entity Framework con sus relaciones y todo lo de mas esto que te pongo aqui es un ejemplo de como se relacionan atraves de estructura de datos. la clase Hija es la que hereda de la padre, y la hija tiene como llave foranea la llave de la clase otro. Yo lo que pregunto es como puedo insertar los datos de la clase Hija cuando ya existe datos en la clase Padre.

Comment: desde la clase hija alli no veo ninguna llave foranea a la clase otro, porque tendrias que tener la clase de navegacion  public Otro Otro {get;set;} en la clase hija y realizar el mapea de esta relacion

Comment: si existe solo que lo omito para no hacer tan extenso la lectura, mira:

Comment: public int otroId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("otroId")]
        public virtual Otro Otro { get; set; }

Comment: y en la clase Otro es asi:

Comment: public Otro()
        {           
            Hija= new HashSet<Hija>();          
        }

Comment: [InverseProperty("Otro")]
        public virtual ICollection<Hija> Hija{ get; set; }

Comment: como te explico toda las propiedades de navagacion existen...

Comment: en el codigo que has publicado no veo el [ForeignKey("otroId")], donde estas esos atributos?

Comment: espera un momento que voy a incluir toda la relacion existente

Answer (score 1):

Para poder insertar una entidad hija con el mism id de la padre tienes que remover la existente

```
var padre = context.Padre.find(1);
context.Entry(padre).State = EntityState.Deleted;

var hijo = new Hijo()
{
    Id = padre.Id;
    Nombre = padre.Nombre,
    Importe = padre.Importe,
    otroId=2;
}
context.Entry(hijo).State = EntityState.Added;

context.SaveChanges();
```

entiendo por el ejemplo que existe en la table Otros un registro con id=2

Comment: Hay que eliminar obligado los datos de la padre para poder insertar la hija, quieres decir que no se puede modificar la padre para insertar los datos de la hija...........Y si lo quiero hacer arrebe tambien hay que hacerlo asi?

Comment: El problema es que no puedo eliminar los datos de la clase padre porque existe otra que tienes datos que hace referencia a sus datos.

Comment: tu respuesta para mi pregunta esta bien pero me habia faltado publicar que existe otra tabla que hace referencia a la Padre y no se pueden eliminar los datos si no es por cascada pero los datos de la tabla historial no la puedo eliminar que puedo hacer en este caso????